# create a Bidimensional object and print it in json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I have some problem creating an object array 2d with javascript (no jquery)

the output should be some one of this:

```
{"Switch":[{"name":"Switch 1","description":"Switch 1"},{"name":"Switch 2","description":"Switch 2"},{"name":"Switch 3","description":"Switch 3"},{"name":"Switch 4","description":"Switch 4"},{"name":"Switch 5","description":"Switch 5"},{"name":"Switch 6","description":"Switch 6"},{"name":"Switch 7","description":"Switch 7"}]}
```

the only one goal I reach is using two different arrays, one for the name and one for the description, doing someting like this:

```
var swName = [];
var swDesc = [];
var i;
var namePrefix = "swtchname";
var descPrefix = "swtchdesc";
var count = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="swtchname"]').length; //if exist swtchname exist olso description

for(i=0;i<count;i++){
    var name;
    var desc;
    name = document.getElementById(namePrefix + i).value;
    desc = document.getElementById(descPrefix + i).value;
    swName.push(name);
    swDesc.push(desc);
}
```

I would like to create an object with two-dimension and put all the data in it.

How can I change this? cause if I create an object like this, it should be easy also print the JSON format, right?

Comment: `X.Switch.push({name: name, description: desc});`, where `X` is the reference to the object containing `Switch` property.

Comment: You should be stringify/parsing... JSON.stringify({"type":"message","details":{"user":"tester1"}}; then parse it when you want to read it.

Comment: main problem here is how creating the object X with Switch property

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `<input>` elements with `swtchname{x}` and `swtchdesc{x}` as `id` where `x` is a number, try something like:

```js
var namePrefix = "swtchname";
var descPrefix = "swtchdesc";
var names = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="swtchname"]');
var X = {
  Switch: []
};

names.forEach(function(i) {
  var desc = document.getElementById(i.id.replace(namePrefix, descPrefix));
  X.Switch.push({
    name: i.value,
    desc: (desc && desc.value) || ''
  });
});

console.log(X);
```

```html
<input id="swtchname1" value="name 1">
<input id="swtchdesc1" value="desc 1">

<input id="swtchname2" value="name 2">
<input id="swtchdesc2" value="desc 2">

<input id="swtchname3" value="name 3">
<input id="swtchdesc3" value="desc 3">

<input id="swtchname4" value="name 4">
<input id="swtchdesc4" value="desc 4">

<input id="swtchname5" value="name 5">
<input id="swtchdesc5" value="desc 5">

<input id="swtchname6" value="name 6">
<input id="swtchdesc6" value="desc 6">
```

Comment: Yeah after a lot of try I found my way!! I did a thing like this:
` code ` var SWarr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  SWarr.push({
   name: document.getElementById(namePrefix + i).value,
   description: document.getElementById(descPrefix + i).value,
  });
 }

 var jsonFormInfo = (JSON.stringify({ Switch: [SWarr] }));`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah after a lot of try I found my way!! I did a thing like this:

```
var SWarr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        SWarr.push({
            name: document.getElementById(namePrefix + i).value,
            description: document.getElementById(descPrefix + i).value,
        });
    }

    var jsonFormInfo = (JSON.stringify({ Switch: [SWarr] }));
```

Thank a lot for the input!